# XML with text tags getting prematurely un-encoded when transformed in XSLT 1.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm working on transforming to HTML a multiple choice quiz stored in XML... the answers include html tags:

> What is the HTML tag used to create a collection of input fields
>   a) <collection>
>   b) <lasso>
>   c) <fieldset>
>   d) No such tag exists

The problem is that while the text is encoded in the XML;

```
  <multiple_choice>
    <question>
      <p style="font-weight: bold">What is the HTML tag used to create a collection of input fields?</p>
    </question>
    <choice value="V1">&lt;collection&gt;</choice>
    <choice value="V2">&lt;lasso/&gt;   </choice>
    <choice value="V3">&lt;fieldset&gt;</choice>
    <choice value="V4">No such tag exists</choice>
  </multiple_choice>
```

...by the time it gets rendered it has been unencoded, and the question displays on the screen with a, b, and c as blank, with a fieldset around d:

[image: Result of XSL]

I found this here on Stack, tinkered it the tiniest bit, and used it:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Replace < encoding "&lt;"" with double encoded string "&amp;lt;" -->
<xsl:template match="choice/text()">

    <xsl:variable name="newtext">
        <xsl:call-template name="string-replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="string" select='.' />
            <xsl:with-param name="from" select='"&lt;"' />
            <xsl:with-param name="to" select='"&amp;lt;"' />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:value-of select="$newtext"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Which works SMASHINGLY if I want to change "fieldset" to "monkey" but if I want to change < , I get no change at all.

I tried it with < and with &lt; and neither worked.

Either using this method or any other method, how do I prevent the &lt; and &gt; from decoding before the render?

### Update 1

String replace is pretty traditional, but I should have thought to include it:

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace" >
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:param name="from" />
    <xsl:param name="to" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string,$from)"> <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,$from)"/><xsl:value-of select="$to"/> <xsl:call-template name="string-replace"> <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,$from)"/> <xsl:with-param name="from" select="$from"/> <xsl:with-param name="to" select="$to"/> </xsl:call-template> 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

### Update 2

Minor eureka moment... I changed the "from" string to "&amp;lt;" and it was able to find it... which is great, I can change it to "[" easily if I wanted...

However I can't change it to &lt;... or even &amp;amp;amp;amp;lt; ... for whatever reason, the xsl will traverse any number of encodes and return an unencoded less than

### Update 3

The actual source I'm recieving at the browser is:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold">What is the HTML tag used to create a collection of input fields?</p>
<input type="radio" value="V1"/><choice value="V1"><collection></choice><br/>
<input type="radio" value="V2"/><choice value="V2"><lasso></choice><br/>
<input type="radio" value="V3"/><choice value="V3"><fieldset></choice><br/>
<input type="radio" value="V4"/><choice value="V4">No such tag exists</choice><br/>
```

The source I desire to receiving at the browser is:

```
<p style="font-weight: bold">What is the HTML tag used to create a collection of input fields?</p>
<input type="radio" value="V1"/><choice value="V1">&lt;collection&gt;</choice><br/>
<input type="radio" value="V2"/><choice value="V2">&lt;lasso&gt;</choice><br/>
<input type="radio" value="V3"/><choice value="V3">&lt;fieldset&gt;</choice><br/>
<input type="radio" value="V4"/><choice value="V4">No such tag exists</choice><br/>
```

Comment: And what does the `string-replace` template look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather confusing. If this is your XML input:

```
<multiple_choice>
    <question>
      <p style="font-weight: bold">What is the HTML tag used to create a collection of input fields?</p>
    </question>
    <choice value="V1">&lt;collection&gt;</choice>
    <choice value="V2">&lt;lasso/&gt;   </choice>
    <choice value="V3">&lt;fieldset&gt;</choice>
    <choice value="V4">No such tag exists</choice>
</multiple_choice>
```

why is it necessary to replace anything? Yoi did not post the expected resulting HTML code, but as an example, applying this stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="choice">
    <input type="radio" value="{@value}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </input><br/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would produce the following **result**:

```
<multiple_choice>
   <question>
      <p style="font-weight: bold">What is the HTML tag used to create a collection of input fields?</p>
   </question>
   <input type="radio" value="V1">&lt;collection&gt;</input>
   <br/>
   <input type="radio" value="V2">&lt;lasso/&gt;   </input>
   <br/>
   <input type="radio" value="V3">&lt;fieldset&gt;</input>
   <br/>
   <input type="radio" value="V4">No such tag exists</input>
   <br/>
</multiple_choice>
```

rendered as:

[image]

Comment: Only it doesn't... it produces three blank radio buttons (because it is rendering the answers as tags) and then "no such tag answer" inside a fieldset... (I added the screenshot to the question)

Comment: @OhkaBaka What are you using to test this? -- P.S. Please edit your question and add the exact output (as code) you would like to receive as the result of the transformation.

Comment: Additional background... this is one part of a larger machine... large enough that I can't post all the associated XSL/XML...

My concern is that, if what you say is correct, and the code as it is SHOULD render a proper result, then there is something deeper in the works that is causing the decode... and that is a can of worms I'd REALLY rather not open today, but it feels like it might be the way.

Comment: Here's a demo showing what is received at the end of the above XSLT transformation: http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cr -- "*this is one part of a larger machine*" That may very well be a key to the problem; if your XSLT processor is not the one doing the serializing of the output, but passing it to some other component further down in the chain, you need to go there and see why is the text getting unescaped.

Comment: Thanks for the assist, I suspect you are correct... (and thanks for sharing that tool, I love me some good online tools)